# r - capitalizing column content before dividing two data frames

Tags: r, dplyr

```
if (!require("dplyr")) install.packages("dplyr");library(dplyr)

ID <- c("AA", "BB", "CC")
ID2 <- c("AAa", "bBB", "ccC")
C1 <- rnorm(3,5,1)
C2 <- rnorm(3,6,1)
C3 <- rnorm(3,7,1)
DF1 <- data.frame(ID, ID2, C1, C2, C3)

ID <- c("AA", "BB", "CC")
ID2 <- c("AAA", "BBb", "CCc")
C1 <- rnorm(3,5,2)
C2 <- rnorm(3,6,2)
C3 <- rnorm(3,7,2)
DF2 <- data.frame(ID, ID2, C1, C2, C3)

DF1 <- DF1 %>%
  mutate(ID2 = toupper(ID2))
DF2 <- DF2 %>%
  mutate(ID2 = toupper(ID2))

DF3 <- DF1[-1]/DF2[-1]
```

My goal is to first capitalize the ID2 column in both DF1 and DF2 before dividing them.

Without the “toupper” code, this script can run without any issue, but once the “toupper” code is added to capitalize ID2, I get this error message: **“Error in FUN(left, right) : non-numeric argument to binary operator”**.

I know when I execute the code DF1[-1]/DF2[-1], the ID2 column will be N/A and irrelevant. I also know I could use "cbind" to combine the ID2 column from DF1 or DF2 later on and then capitalize it.

I’m only curious to know:

1. Why my code to capitalize column “ID2” in DF1 and DF2 before the
   division didn’t work?
2. How to edit my code so that column “ID2” in DF1 and DF2 can be
   capitalized before the division?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are two columns ('ID', 'ID2') that are `character` class

```
str(DF1)
#'data.frame':  3 obs. of  5 variables:
# $ ID : chr  "AA" "BB" "CC"
# $ ID2: chr  "AAA" "BBB" "CCC"
# $ C1 : num  3.29 7.05 4.74
# $ C2 : num  5.85 5.36 7.56
# $ C3 : num  9.39 8.06 7.94
```

So, instead of `-1` i.e. to remove the first column, we need to remove the 1st and 2nd

```
DF3 <- DF1
DF3[-(1:2)] <- DF1[-c(1:2)]/DF2[-(1:2)]    
DF3
#  ID ID2        C1        C2       C3
#1 AA AAA 0.4377081 0.9719322 1.221487
#2 BB BBB 3.6132329 0.7321244 1.105958
#3 CC CCC 0.9420565 0.8596261 1.115767
```

Comment: Thanks Akrun, I think this will work. 
But I still don’t understand why capitalizing ID2 will throw me an error. Without the “toupper” code, there are still ID1 and ID2 as character class and the code DF1[-1]/DF2[-1] still works without any errors (it will only show a warning about ID2 being non-numeric and will just return NA)

Comment: @VincentXu. It is only because you created the ID1, ID2 columns while constructing the data.frame.  So, there are two character columns to begin with.  `toupper` is just converting the second column to upper case.  If you had only created the dataset with `ID1, and C1, C2, C3, then your code would work because ID1 would be the first column and all others are numeric